# SVG: Best way to fill a rect with three colors

Tags: svg

I have an application where a workflow is represented using SVG as shown in the picture.

Each task (rectangle) has three properties: **start**, **location** and **end**. We want to visualize these properties using colors. The left side of the task color shows the start, the right side of the task shows the end and the middle of the task shows location.

For example tasks 0, 12, and 11 start at the same time, end at the same time and take place in the same location therefore they have the same color on the left side, right side and middle.

Same with tasks (1, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8), (4, 6), (5, 7).

The user can change these properties so we need to change the colors dynamically.

I was thinking of two ways to fill the rectangles.

1. **Have three  elements** - left, middle, right - and color each one accordingly. when the user changes a property the fill property of the rectangle will be changed

   *Downside*: for each task we will have three more "rect" elements and for a large number of tasks this can lead to slow performance
2. **Use Linear Gradients** to color the tasks. The gradients will have three stops.

   *Downside*: we will need to dynamically create/delete "linearGradients" before assigning them to the fill style of the tasks.

I was thinking that solution #2 (gradients) is better but I was wondering if there is something that I do not consider OR if there is another better solution.

[image]

Comment: If you choose gradients, probably you will need a gradient per rect. Every linear gradient would have 6 stops that you will need to update. If you choose the other option you will need a group with 4 rectangles: the main rectangle and 3 other for the color. So you will need to update 3 rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the first approach (additional "rect" elements). The reasons:

1. More natural way to do it
2. Tested with a large number of "tasks" (100) and the performance is not affected.